# Python Package Import Design

Tags: python, installation, import

I have a python package that works perfectly if it's installed with `python setup.py install`, however, i cannot run the package locally.

Here is my package structure:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── script1.py
│   ├── script2.py
│   ├── main.py
├── setup.py
```

Here is the import setup in `main.py`:

```
from package.script1 import Class
from package.script2 import function
```

This works great if I install the package and then `import package`, but I cannot run `python package/main.py` locally or I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'`

Note: `__init__.py` is empty.

Thank you so much for any and all help :)

Comment: `__init__.py` should be importing all of the other scripts and using `__all__` to set which ones can be imported. Is the root of your project in the current cd / added to python path?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eric. I don't believe I've set my python path. Should that be done in `__init__.py`? Can you post an example of `__all__`?

Comment: for example, `import script1; import script2` and then `__all__ = ['script1', 'script2']`. You can look at some open source projects written in python if you want to see how it works in practice.